# How to use mongodb query to compare the element in DB to another element in an array stored in same collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my question.

This is my sample records

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9b69fae4757402b4b4ca0d"), 
    "status_changed_utc" : [
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-05-20T23:03:10.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(2), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-05-23T23:04:03.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(4), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-05-23T23:05:06.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(5), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-05-23T23:05:07.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(6), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-05-23T23:05:09.000+0000")
        }
    ], 
    "requested_completion_utc" : ISODate("2019-05-22T23:05:09.000+0000")
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9b69fae4757402b4b4ca1e"), 
    "status_changed_utc" : [
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-06-20T23:03:10.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(2), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-07-23T23:04:03.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(4), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-07-23T23:05:06.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(5), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-05-23T23:05:07.000+0000")
        }, 
        {
            "status" : NumberInt(6), 
            "time" : ISODate("2019-07-23T23:05:09.000+0000")
        }
    ], 
    "requested_completion_utc" : ISODate("2019-08-22T23:05:09.000+0000")
},
```

I expect to find out the record which the date of the "requested_completion_utc" field larger than the date from the "status_changed_utc" field when "status_changed_utc.status" is NumberInt(2).

In this example, I expected to get the second record.

Except for $unwind function, is there any other ways to handle this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, we found the answer.

```
db.getCollection("test").aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $match: {
            {
                $expr: {
                    $gt:[
                        {   
                            $size: {
                                $filter:{
                                    "input":"$status_changed_utc",
                                    "as":"doc",
                                    "cond":{
                                        $and: [
                                            {
                                                $eq:["$$doc.status",2]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                $gt:["$$doc.time", "$requested_completion_utc"]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }       
                        },
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },

  ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `NumberInt(2)` is always in the second position of the array. It should be pretty easy.

```
db.whatever.find({ $expr: { $gt: [ "$requested_completion_utc" , "$status_changed_utc.1" ] } })
```

Comment: Hi Deda, the position of NumberInt(2) is random.

Comment: Then you'll need some complex aggregation query with filter, grouping, and matching, sorry it doesn't worth my time.

Answer (score 0):

the requirement is to find the record that meet the following standard, how to write the query without using unwind?

requested_completion_utc > status_changed_utc.time and status_changed_utc.status=2, where the status_changed_utc.time is from the record that has status_changed_utc.status=2